# Is it possible to run JavaScript within a webBrowser Control without accessing a specific page?

Tags: c#, html, browser, webbrowser-control, stringbuilder

I am building a web page live as output for my application.  This means that I'm editing the document text directly, instead of pointing the control to a file.  I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type = "text/css"> 
.circle {
    position:relative;
    moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;

    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color:#33FF00;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var step = 0;
var color= '#0000FF';
function timer()
{
    var t=setTimeout("switchColor()",125);
}
function switchColor()
{
    if (step == 0) {color='#33FF00';}
    if (step == 1) {color='#33FF00';}
    if (step == 2) {color='#22AA55';}
    if (step == 3) {color='#1155AA';}
    if (step == 4) {color='#0000FF';}
    if (step == 5) {color='#0000FF';}
    if (step == 6) {color='#1155AA';}
    if (step == 7) {color='#22AA55';}
    step = step+1;
    if (step > 7) { step = 0;}

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')
    for (var i = 0;i <elements.length;i++)
    {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor=color;
    }

    timer()
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="timer()" >
<div id="test" class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle"></div><div class="circle"></div>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

That code is then set as the documentText of a webBrowser control by using a stringBuilder, adding each line with the StringBuilder.AppendLine() function, and then converting the entire stringBuilder to a string.

I get the error that the getElementsByClassName function is not supported, and nothing happens.  The html runs perfectly on its own.

Comment: When I copy the code you have to a blank html page and view it in IE I get an error: Object doesn't support this property or method.  Line 41 which is the line with GetElementsByClassName.  If it doesn't work in IE it won't work in the WebBrowserControl.

Comment: I don't get errors in Internet Explorer, but the code does not work as well as it does in Firefox. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: My understanding is that the WebBrowserControl uses the IE engine, so you just need to make it work in IE.

Comment: Try loading a blank HTML page first.  I have a feeling the DOM is incomplete if you just try to shove HTML text in a blank control

Comment: It is a problem with that specific getElementsByClassName Command.  I didn't check if it existed in IE first. Alas, it does not.  I figured my code was simple enough that I could test in Firefox without issues. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser Control can run javascript live, but it has the same limitations as Internet Explorer.  Any commands used within the control need to be able to run in Internet Explorer on the associated machine.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for you, I propose that you use jQuery.  It can find elements that have a certain class and works great in IE.  Specifically look at the class selector.

[www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You´ll need to use getElementsByTagName('*'), iterate over the list and verify if each item has the desired className.